# returning a word from getword using int; possible typo in binsearch

Tags: c, return, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm finally finishing K&R, but encountered yet another unclear code. Chapter 6.3/6.4

1. Referring to getword. How can it return int and that is supposed to be a word. I understand that it returns word[0] which is the first letter. However in my opinion, if I wanted to return a word, I'd introduce something like char *getword. Am I right?
   How is int able to indicate it is a word?
2. Still about getword: Supposing I enter "in " and after space I push enter. getword reads 'i' as it is not a space, and isalpha so the first if is omitted. What happens then?
3. I marked the line in binsearch. Don't You think it should be high = mid - 1; there?

```
int getword(char *word, int lim) {
    char *w = word;
    int c;

    while (isspace(c = getch()))
    {}
    if (c != EOF) {
        *w++ = c;
    }

    if (!isalpha(c)) {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }
    for ( ; --lim > 0; w++) {
        if (!isalnum(*w = getch())) {
            ungetch(*w);
            break;
        }
    }
    *w = '\0';
    return word[0];
}
```

---

```
/* binsearch: find word in tab[0]...tab[n-1] */
struct key *binsearch(char *word, struck key *tab, int n)
{
    int cond;
    struct key *low = &tab[0];
    struct key *high = &tab[n];
    struct key *mid;
    while (low < high) {
        mid = low + (high-low) / 2;
        if ((cond = strcmp(word, mid->word)) < 0)
            high = mid; /* [3] */
        else if (cond > 0)
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: @unwind It's because the one with binsearch is a really short & not complicated case. I'd be embarrassed to create a topic with such a negligible question ;)

Comment: Here, questions are just that, questions. Not topics for discussion, not headlines, not groups of thoughts. The unit you can post here on Stack Overflow is a single question, so that's exactly what you should use them for. Absolutely no chance of anyone finding that offensive, so you shouldn't be embarrassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, if the function would return a word, it'd be rather `char *getword()`. However, according to K&R

> The function value is the first character of the word, or EOF for end of file, or the character itself if it is not alphabetic

Returning an `int` is ok, as in C, a character is like an `int` having only 8 bits, in the [-128, +127] range.

So where the word is returned?
In the `char *word` given as parameter. Initially `char *w` gets a copy of the `word` pointer, and then the characters read are set into the memory pointed to by `w`.

Having `"in "` in the input buffer, `isspace` would return false, and `c` is assigned the non-space character. Then, `*w++` put that character at position [0] of word (*i*) increments the `w` pointer (`++`). `word[0]` contains 'i'.

The `!isalpha` test is false, thus that part is skipped.

Then characters are read from the input and stored into the next `w` position, until a non alphanumeric entry is read (or limit `lim` is reached) - in this non-alphanumeric case, the character read is actually put back into the input buffer, and `w` - which contains that undesired char - is not incremented (due to `break`). Then the following `*w = '\0'` overwrites that non-alpha char, and "close" the C string (in C strings ends with a character having a 0 value).

In your example, that stores 'n' in `w`, increments `w`, then stores ' ' into `w` and performs the code for `!isalnum`, i.e. breaks the loop. Then since `w` was not incremented after storing ' ', the `*w = '\0'` replaces the space, and "closes" the string.

[*the other half of the question has already been answered by someone else*]

Comment: `int` might be used to distinguish EOF from a valid char. The standard doesn't specify whether `char` is signed or unsigned so the -128,+127 bit is wrong.

Comment: ring0 and @J.F.Sebastian (since You commented here, I'll notify You as well).  Thanks, but still I don't understand, even with Your explanation. You omitted how the main() can "know" that word[0], being let's say = 'i', has a missing part of "dea" - together "idea".

Comment: @PeterKowalski: `word` is a pointer. If you modify characters it points to in getword() then main() sees new values. getword() returns its result in the first parameter because C doesn't allow to return multiple values (one value to indicate EOF, another to store the result).

Comment: @JF [-128,+127] is a range. For the sake of clarity (and most of current implementations sign the char) a range was provided in the answer (and for unsigned char, that would be [0,255]), in order to show that in C the same math can be applied to a signed char and, say, int, within a different range (and resp. unsigned char, and unsigned int).

Answer (score 2):

`high = mid` is correct. The right boundary is not included. Notice that initially `high = &tab[n]` i.e., it points past the last element in `tab`.